# function in a function return value

Tags: node.js, function, return-value

import.js

```
exports.getConfig = function() {
  return api.getConfig();

};
```

test.js

```
// Aanmaken lightBridge
obj = reflector.getObj();
console.log(obj);

// Toon alle lichten
obj.getConfig().then(function(config) {
    console.log(config);
}).done();
```

In the last snippet it's using the function of 
When I call the getConfig() i want to have the output that is in variable config. The problem is now when I want to log the variable test I recieve undefined.

If I console.log(config) instead of return config; it works perfectly. Seems weird.

The out result when I want to use it is like varia.getConfig() => output of config.

Comment: Where is the `test` variable you mention?

Comment: @HugoWood that isn't needed actually. it's just where you see obj.getConfig().then(function(config){ console.log(config); } that must send a response.send(config) instead. But I need to have the returned value of config first

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Can't you do `response.send(config)` inside of the callback at line 7 of `test.js`?

Comment: Well I want to call the code from //Toon alle lichten in an API call. That's the reason why I need to have that config variable as a return

Answer (score 1):

test exist only on your function not outside. You can try something like this but it may be dirty.

```
    var test;
    exports.getConfig = function() {
      api.getConfig(function(err, config) {
        if (err) throw err;
        test = config;
    });
```

Comment: The variable test is not needed tbh. Only tried to fix it on that way :P

Isn't there another way instead of defining it to a variable?. Isn't it posible to return it to the exports.getConfig()?

Comment: You can make a promise of it. It should be the better way.

Comment: I've updated main field. How can I send then still the result to exports.getConfig? And I need to use it on another file with obj.getConfig(); So the console.log(config) needs to be changed into res.send(JSON.stringify(config)); So I can send the output to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to consume an asynchronous function as if it was synchronous. You cannot do that. What you can do is return a promise from `getConfig`.

```
exports.getConfig = function() {
  return api.getConfig();
};
```

Then your module can be consumed like this:

```
const myModule = require('my-module');
myModule.getConfig().then(function(config) {
    console.log(config);
});
```

From the comments it sounds like you are using Express. If you want to send `config` in an HTTP response with Express you can do this:

```
app.get('/config', function(request, response) {
    myModule.getConfig().then(function(config) {
        response.send(config);
    });
});
```

Comment: Y this is closely to my solution I think. I recieve this now in my startup node